# .Current link styling on CSS only works on the 1st page and doesn't transfer to the other

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styling

So the css that I have works for both html pages, however, the current link styling only works on the first page and doesn't transfer to the 2nd page when clicked. Do you know why this would be?

css that handles the current link styling

```
li.current > a:link {
    border-bottom: 0.3px solid #000000;
}
```

1st page html (works on this)

```
<!--Header-->
<header class="boxed" id="header-white">
    <div class="header-margin">
        <div class="logo"><a class="ajax-link" href="index-2.html">DAVIT AVOYAN</a></div>
        <ul class="header-nav">
            <li class = "current"><a class="ajax-link" href="index-2.html">UX PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a class="ajax-link" href="about-me.html">About me</a></li>
        </ul>
```

2nd html page (works on this one, only if opened first)

```
<!--Header-->
<header class="boxed" id="header-white">
    <div class="header-margin">
        <div class="logo"><a class="ajax-link" href="index-2.html">DAVIT AVOYAN</a></div>
        <ul class="header-nav">
            <li><a class="ajax-link" href="index-2.html">UX PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li class = "current"><a class="ajax-link" href="about-me.html">About me</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: How are you including the CSS in your HTML pages?

Comment: it's an external file. It definitely works properly for both pages - they are styled. This is such a weird issue. The page that I open first, will have the "current" styling and it won't switch to the other. But both are able to have the styling.

Comment: Which other styling?  And how are you including the styles?  It sounds like something is going on with how you're including the styles.

Comment: I was referring to the other page. There is only one styling.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: You've got the `ajax-link` class on each of the anchors, I'm guessing this means a page reload doesn't happen when the anchors are clicked?

Comment: If so, could you post your AJAX loading code?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Please find my AJAX code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351338/ajax-wont-let-css-current-link-styling-work-properly

Answer (score 2):

Please try below css for get link in second page. You need to put "a:visited" property.

```
<style type="text/css">
    li.current > a:link {
        border-bottom: 0.3px solid green;
        color: red;
    }
    li.current > a:visited {
        border-bottom: 0.3px solid green;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, but visited is different. Isn't it any link that the user has already visited? This would style all the links that the user clicks on, no? I only want the link they are currently on to be styled.

Comment: @David Did you put the style css in both pages ?

Comment: @Jalpa has the correct solution here.  I added my own answer below with further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is expected.  The `:link` pseudo-class refers to links that have never been visited.  By definition, the user must have clicked the link to the current page to get to it, so it will not be selected by `:link`.

You need to use `li.current > a:visited`.

Comment: No styling happens at all with this being in my css instead of :link. Why would this be? Please note, that the css definitely works properly on both pages - I have a lot of other styling that works flawlessly on both pages from this one css document.

Comment: Have you inspected the link in the debugger to see what pseudo-class is getting applied?  You might need to add an :active style, if the link is selected.

Comment: I have an :active style. And it works. When I look at the elements after it renders, it shows "current" class one hierarchy above my nav links and only applies to the page that loaded first - does not change if I click on the other.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted all the code relevant to this problem.

Comment: It is a LOT of code. I can't fit it into a post - 3 huge documents (2 HTML and 1 CSS). Are there any particular parts that would be helpful?

Comment: Anything related to the link you're having a problem with.  Like all the styles that could be applied to it.

Comment: Also, you say that :link refers to sites that were never visited. But the irony is that it DOES only style the link that the user clicked on first. It's very confusing.

Comment: Now I'm confused.  I thought the current link (that was presumably clicked, to get to that page), was not being styled.  What is and isn't being styled?

Comment: As I explained in the original post, only the original page on which you're on gets styled (it can be either first or second). After you click on the next page, the styling does not get transferred. That is the issue.

Comment: does not let me edit my post, so putting the css here, sorry:

Comment: Not working here either. Could I message you perhaps? Was this explanation of the problem a bit clearer?

Comment: Ah, it says I don't have enough reputation to chat. But hey, I checked the page source again, and what happens is that just that area in my html where I have the current class, doesn't get updated for the page that I click, but everything else does. Is this a familiar problem to you?

Comment: Is this a whole page load or are you loading with ajax?  How are you applying the .current class, with PHP or something else?

Comment: with ajax. Wait, what php? This is just a css class?

Comment: Ok, can you show me how you're loading the page with ajax?

Comment: (I tried commenting it out and it looks like ajax IS the problem, since the css worked properly after I commented it out).

Comment: here is my ajax code that started the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351338/ajax-wont-let-css-current-link-styling-work-properly