# Ajax won't let css current link styling work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

This is my problematic ajax file. Please also refer to my original css question here: [.Current link styling on CSS only works on the 1st page and doesn't transfer to the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349803/current-link-styling-on-css-only-works-on-the-1st-page-and-doesnt-transfer-to/34350034?noredirect=1#comment56442165_34350034)

How can I fix this Ajax code so that starts letting me apply my current link styling to the actual current page?

```
$("a.ajax-link").live("click", function(){
$this = $(this);
var link = $this.attr('href');
var current_url = $(location).attr('href'); 

if( link != current_url && link != '#' ) { 
    $.ajax({
        url:link,
        processData:true, 
        dataType:'html', 
        success:function(data){
            document.title = $(data).filter('title').text(); 
            current_url = link;
            if (typeof history.pushState != 'undefined') 
                history.pushState(data, 'Page', link);

            setTimeout(function(){                      
                $('#preloader').delay(50).fadeIn(600);
                $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({ scrollTop:  0  },1000);                       

                setTimeout(function(){

                    $('#ajax-content').html($(data).filter('#ajax-content').html());
                    $('#ajax-sidebar').html($(data).filter('#ajax-sidebar').html());

                    $('body').waitForImages({
                        finished: function() {
                            Website();
                            backLoading();
                            $('.opacity-nav').delay(50).fadeOut(600);
                        },                                      
                        waitForAll: true
                    });                             
                },1000);
            },0);
        }
    });
}
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just need to remove the `current` class from previous `<li class = "current">` and need to apply it to current `<a>` tag's parent `<li>` tag.

This can be done in following way:

```
$("a.ajax-link").live("click", function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var link = $this.attr('href');
    var current_url = $(location).attr('href'); 

    if( link != current_url && link != '#' ) { 
        $.ajax({
            url:link,
            processData:true, 
            dataType:'html', 
            success:function(data){

                //code to apply current class to current li

                if($this.parent("div.logo").length == 0){
                    $("li.current").removeClass("current");
                    $this.parent("li").addClass("current");
                }
                //code ends here

                document.title = $(data).filter('title').text(); 
                current_url = link;
                if (typeof history.pushState != 'undefined') 
                    history.pushState(data, 'Page', link);

                setTimeout(function(){                      
                    $('#preloader').delay(50).fadeIn(600);
                    $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({ scrollTop:  0  },1000);                       

                    setTimeout(function(){

                        $('#ajax-content').html($(data).filter('#ajax-content').html());
                        $('#ajax-sidebar').html($(data).filter('#ajax-sidebar').html());

                        $('body').waitForImages({
                            finished: function() {
                                Website();
                                backLoading();
                                $('.opacity-nav').delay(50).fadeOut(600);
                            },                                      
                            waitForAll: true
                        });                             
                    },1000);
                },0);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ah, follow-up question! The way this works is it's connected to the actual link right? Is there a way to make it check the url instead? Because I need the home page to stay active when the logo is also clicked. With this code, the styling of the home page goes away when the logo is clicked. Do you understand the problem? Let me know if I need to elaborate. But thanks so much for helping me with that code1

Comment: @David - updated the answer to avoid `addClass` whenever logo link is clicked. I hope I understood you.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately, the current link still gets unstyled as soon as you click the logo :/ the logo actually leads to the same page, but for some reason, the current link gets unstyled. Any thoughts?

Comment: Now it works better! I see what you did there in the code :) The only thing is if you're at the other page and you click on the logo to go to the home page, the previous page remains styled and home page remains inactive.